# Carbon count minutes from timestamp

Tags: php, php-carbon

I am working with the PHP Carbon library. And I am trying to get the total time in minutes from a timestamp.

```
$time = new Carbon('02:13:23');
```

And I was wondering if there is a function like countMinutes() or totalMinutes() that would return in this case **133.38** which is 2 hours + 13 min + 23 sec. = 133.38

Or do I have to do it myself without the help of the library .. 120+13+(23/60)

Comment: i have a query. are you looking for 120+13+(23/60) or 60+13+(23/60) ?

Answer (score 4):

Try the below code :

```
$time = Carbon::createFromTimeString('02:13:23');
$start_of_day = Carbon::createFromTimeString('02:13:23')->startOfDay();
$total_minutes = $time->diffInMinutes($start_of_day);

dd($time,$start_of_day,$total_minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for getting minutes from a `Carbon` object.

```
// Create Carbon object from a specific date
$time = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '02:13:23');

// Get days, hours and then minutes
$days = $startDate->diffInDays($time);
$hours = $startDate->copy()->addDays($days)->diffInHours($time);
$minutes = $startDate->copy()->addDays($days)->addHours($hours)->diffInMinutes($time);

echo $minutes;
```

[Check the Carbon's documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference), there is a lot of good examples to get started.

Good luck!

Comment: That's a long code to get minutes. Isn't there something shorter like $time->getMinutes(); ?

Comment: You could use the `isoFormat()` method. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Not working, it just echos the letter 'i'.echo $time->isoFormat('i');

Comment: You need to `echo` the result of the `isoFormat()` method. Sorry, my answer has been updated.

Comment: It still echos just the letter i

Comment: Check https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters. You should able to use the Carbon's getters to retrieve the total minutes of your `Carbon` object but, as far as i am concerned, i think that my first solution is the easiest to use..